# Delphi - MyDAC - Fast Report

Tags: mysql, delphi, fastreport, mydac

I have no problem generating a report from a MySQL query or table.
The problem starts when I want to add a variable in the report in each row.

For example, table `"PRODUCTS":  ID|PRODUCT-NAME|SHELF-LIFE`

What's the best practice if I want to generate a report that shows me

`ID` | `NAME` | `EXPIRE-DAY`

Where: `EXPIRE-DAY` = `TODAY` + `SHELF-LIFE`

Thanks in advance for your help, even a link would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three Options:

1. Use FR-functions to add your days.
2. Use a variable in FR and calculate in Delphi via .OnGetValue-event
3. Add the calculation of EXPIRE-DAY to your MySQL-Query

something like:

```
Select ID, NAME, SHELF-LIFE, DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL SHELF-LIFE DAY) as EXPIRE-DAY from mytable
```

Comment: 4) or use the expression?

Answer (score 0):

You may use FR's internal function DATE to get current date: `[Date + <YourDatasetName."SHELF-LIFE">]`

Comment: `DATE` is not a function but a [system variable](https://www.fast-report.com/documentation/UserManFrNET-en/index.html?usesystemvariablesinexpressions.htm).

Comment: Date is function too. See Functions tab in the Data Tree or use such script `begin
     ShowMessage(Date);
     ShowMessage(<Date>);         
end.`

Comment: Not in term of expressions, which is what you've shown. Besides, I guess those two notations would return different values, `<Date>` one refers to that system variable (the same you used in the expression in your answer) whilst `Date` is a function exported by PascalScript and returns the same as Delphi, that is, a value of current date with time portion set to 0 which differs from a date time value returned by that variable. P.S. such script would fail.

Comment: Such script `procedure ReportTitle1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  ShowMessage(Date);
  ShowMessage(<Date>);
  ShowMessage(Now);
  ShowMessage(Time);
  ShowMessage(<Time>);
end;` works OK. Tested with FR Enterprise 5.6.2

Comment: Sorry, then they must have add overloads for `ShowMessage` procedure, because the one exported from PascalScript accepts only string parameters. From what you say it accepts also `TDateTime` parameters. Good to know. Thanks!